# Previous fragment visible behind current one after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my main activity I am displaying several fragments depending on option chosen by the user. When screen is rotated and then fragment changed, the previous fragment, one that was visible while rotating screen, is transparent and still visible behind or over new one. I am adding fragments using `add()` method and then removing old ones with `remove()`. I am aware that simply using `replace()` would fix my problem but my main fragment contains many network and database calls on create and I would like to remember its state rather than make many unnecessary calls. 
Why does my problem even occur when I am removing fragments other than the main one? How can I fix it?
Here is how I am setting my fragments:

```
public void setFragment(FragmentEnum fragmentEnum, @Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Fragment oldFragment = getCurrentFragment();       

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        currentFragment = fragmentEnum;
        mMapFragment = (MainMapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(MainMapFragment.TAG);
        if (mMapFragment == null) {
            mMapFragment = MainMapFragment.newInstance(bundle);
        }

        if (fragmentEnum == FragmentEnum.MAP) {
            if (!mMapFragment.isAdded()) {
                ft.add(R.id.container_contents, mMapFragment, MainMapFragment.TAG);
            }
            if (oldFragment != null && !(oldFragment instanceof MainMapFragment)) {
                ft.remove(oldFragment);
            }
            ft.show(mMapFragment);
            if (mNavigationDrawerFragment != null) mNavigationDrawerFragment.unselectItems();
        } else {
            ft.hide(mMapFragment);
            Fragment newFragment = null;
            String tag = null;
            switch (fragmentEnum) {
                case LIST:
                    newFragment = MainListFragment.newInstance();
                    tag = MainListFragment.TAG;                        
                    break;
                case FAVORITE:
                    newFragment = MainFavoriteFragment.newInstance();
                    tag = MainFavoriteFragment.TAG;
                    break;
                case ADD:
                    newFragment = MainAddFragment.newInstance();
                    tag = MainAddFragment.TAG;
                    break;
                case USER:
                    newFragment = MainUserFragment.newInstance();
                    tag = MainUserFragment.TAG;
                    break;
            }

            ft.add(R.id.container_contents, newFragment, tag);
            if (oldFragment != null && !(oldFragment instanceof MainMapFragment)) {
                ft.remove(oldFragment);
            }
            ft.show(newFragment);            
        }

        ft.commit();        
    }

@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putSerializable(SAVE_STATE_CURR_FRG, currentFragment);
    }

onCreate(){
...
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            FragmentEnum savedFragmentEnum = (FragmentEnum) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(SAVE_STATE_CURR_FRG);            
                setFragment(savedFragmentEnum, null);            
        }
...
}
```

Comment: use `ft.replace` instead of add if that is not specific to your flow

Comment: use `ViewModels` arc component with fragment to preserve state. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html